# Unity canvas overlap using networking

Tags: networking, unity-game-engine, multiplayer

I am using the new unity networking using unity 5.3.1 , my player prefab is a UI canvas , so when another client joins the canvas's overlap and I cannot press any button on host or client .

What i want is to disable other canvase's on each players game and just leave the local players canvase active , I have tried islocalplayer , isclient ,isserver but nothing works .

Is there a way around this please do tell.

Comment: I'm not sure how your canvases are related to networking but using multiple canvases is always a bad idea and should be avoided where possible. I'm sure you can make your player a simple RectTransform.

Comment: @NikaKasradze So for that i have to manually spawn my player and make it the child of canvas? . Btw I am making a card game so i made the canvas the player prefab thats why I wanted to ask is there a way to setActive(false) the client canvas some way because all the tutorials show to use player code inside islocalplayer bool check.

Comment: @NikaKasradze thinking of making the player the child of canvas , would it not be the same problem again as the raycasting depends on the level of hierarchy in the canvas , the clients child will have priority and I still wont be able to click on the host ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out and as @NikaKasradze said use only one canvas and put all gui listeners in the islocalplayer bool check .

Answer (score 2):

Here are some options I can think of:

1) Instead of making canvas a player object, make panel a player object, so that all your players are different panels under same canvas. Now, when object are under same canvas, they ray casting order is determined by the order in hierarchy.

The objects that are **lower** in the hierarchy occlude those that are higher. So, what you can do is moving your player object to the **lowest** position in objects hierarchy, so that it will occlude all other players. This can be done using Transform methods [SetSiblingIndex](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetSiblingIndex.html) and [GetSiblingIndex](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.GetSiblingIndex.html), like

```
 transform.SetSiblingIndex(100000/*some big number*/);
```

2) Disable raycasting on all other players - what if you can click some component on canvas or not is whether it is a raycast target. Images and Text components can be raycast targets, or more generally any component that inherits from [Graphics](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Graphic.html). You can iterate over all components of type Graphics in all players except the local player and mark `raycastTarget = false`.

Comment: cool thanks I will try that also if I get into more problems but im going with my answer at the moment . upvoted